# Robocopy matching files in subdirectories

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy

I'm trying to write a robocopy script which will copy all error files, regardless of what subfolder they are in, to one location.

I've done `robocopy "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft" "D:\ErrorLogs" *.err /s`, but that also copies the subfolder over.

I want all of the .err files to be in D:\ErrorLogs, regardless of whether they were originally in a subfolder or not.

Is that possible?

Comment: do you need specifically Robocopy? Also, what about duplicate names?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that `Robocopy.exe` will ignore subdirectory paths. There will likely be directories and/or file that cannot be accessed, so `-ErrorAction` can be used.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "${Env:PROGRAMDATA}\Microsoft" -Filter '*.err' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Copy-Item -Destination 'D:\ErrorLogs'
```